# Error opening socket to server while connecting to database

Tags: database, docker, networking, jboss

When my application server is running, Jboss is not able to connect to DB. I am  running docker DB2 image and not using local DB. I am running Docker on Virtual Box. Application is opening socket to VirtualBox IP instead of localhost. Error says:

Error says: 
`Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory : Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /192.168.56.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001`....Where 192.168.56.1 is my Virtual Box Ip. I can connect my DB2 docker image through DB2 client running on local but not with my application.

Logs:

```
2019-02-11 18:20:16,806  INFO [ost-startStop-1 ation.ConfigurationClassParser] - Properties location [/opt/demandtec/common/conf/jms.properties] not resolvable: class path resource [opt/demandtec/common/conf/jms.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2019-02-11 18:20:17,877  INFO [ost-startStop-1 redAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-02-11 18:20:18,683  INFO [ost-startStop-1 dtec.message.DestReserverBeans] - Loading defalt queue topic definitions
2019-02-11 18:20:18,736  INFO [ost-startStop-1 mandtec.global.DTServiceConfig] - init jndi template
2019-02-11 18:20:18,764  INFO [ost-startStop-1 dtec.global.DTRemotingServices] - Start Locate Registry with port: 3099
2019-02-11 18:20:22,685  INFO [ost-startStop-1 ssage.activemq.DTAMQJmsService] - amq connect meta data created
2019-02-11 18:20:22,691  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: QueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,697  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: TopicConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,698  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: PromoCPQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,698  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: PerishableQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,698  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: AMEQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,698  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: FarmQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,720  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: IAMTopicConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,720  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: CTSQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,721  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: GlobalQueueConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,722  INFO [ost-startStop-1 .message.InitConnectionFactory] - export: GlobalTopicConnectionFactory as interface com.ibm.demandtec.mq.RemoteConnectFactory
2019-02-11 18:20:22,731  INFO [ost-startStop-1 ndtec.mq.DTMQConnectionFactory] - Init class: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory, with: {brokerURL=tcp://IBM217-PC0BY3X9:61616, trustAllPackages=true}
2019-02-11 18:20:22,992  INFO [ost-startStop-1 ndtec.mq.DTMQConnectionFactory] - Init class: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory, with: {brokerURL=tcp://IBM217-PC0BY3X9:61616, clientID=IBM217-PC0BY3X9.IAM, trustAllPackages=true}
2019-02-11 18:20:23,357  WARN [ost-startStop-1 .commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] - The requested JMX name [demandtec.com_optimization] was not valid and will be ignored.
2019-02-11 18:20:53,117  INFO [pool-2-thread-1 .demandtec.global.DTMDBService] - Startup AdminMDB
2019-02-11 18:20:54,241  INFO [pool-2-thread-1 .demandtec.global.DTMDBService] - Startup IAM as clientid:IBM217-PC0BY3X9_appiam
2019-02-11 18:30:31,001  WARN [ost-startStop-1 emandtec.dal.ConnectionHandler] - JBossPoolException! Failed getting connection to Optimization for demandtec.com
2019-02-11 18:30:31,001  WARN [ost-startStop-1 emandtec.dal.ConnectionHandler] - cause: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.22.29] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /192.168.56.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001)
2019-02-11 18:30:31,001  WARN [ost-startStop-1 emandtec.dal.ConnectionHandler] - will attempt one more time.
2019-02-11 18:30:31,001  WARN [ost-startStop-1 .commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] - The requested JMX name [demandtec.com_optimization] was not valid and will be ignored.
```

Database: DB2; OS: Windows7/ Docker running on Oracle VirtualBox; Framework: J2EE; App-Server: Jboss

Comment: It can be a number of things causing that. Have you tried connecting from in the container? Then from in you VM?

Comment: As I said I can access DB2 image through DB client running in my local but my application server while connecting shows this error..

Comment: Ok, so, not a docker issue maybe. A misconfiguration? Du you have a config file or some code to show?

Comment: Product I am working on is huge..will take some efforts in finding DB config files. U can suggest me in which direction I can investigate or what steps can I take. Please post your steps in answer section instead of comment. If it works, your ans may get acceptance.

Comment: I would like to but i'm taking a lot of guesses here. What framework? Database type? OS? Answers might be misleading. Is there any DB2 logs, when you try to connect with Jboss, or is there something else denying access?

Comment: Gave some more info on Question..Pls continue this by posting in Answer section, otherwise this thread will go on.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the same problem using `ibmcom/db2` community edition image. It works well when I start the container on MacOS. Then if I start the container in virtualbox environment, jdbc connection fails.

```
[jcc][10521][13706]Command : java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -user db2inst1 -password ******** -url jdbc:db2://0.0.0.0:50000/testdb


[jcc][10512][13714]Failed to create connection.
  SQLCODE: -4499
  SQLSTATE: 08001
  Message: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.12.55] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

Someone suspect it is because of ipv6. So I run `docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=test123 -e DBNAME=testdb -v /home/vagrant/database:/database ibmcom/db2` to start a container. Then get into container with `docker exec -it mydb2 bash`. Remove serveral ipv6 lines and keep only following in `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.17.0.2      def55f9a8b0f
```

Quit and remove this container. Restart container with command `docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 0.0.0.0:50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=test123 -e DBNAME=testdb -v /home/vagrant/database:/database ibmcom/db2`.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                          NAMES
4fbaec4a46ac   ibmcom/db2   "/var/db2_setup/lib/…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes   22/tcp, 55000/tcp, 60006-60007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   mydb2
```

Wait for a few moments, JDBC connection works.

```
[jcc][10516][13709]Test Connection Successful.

DB product version = SQL11056
DB product name = DB2/LINUXX8664
DB URL = jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/testdb
DB Drivername = IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
DB OS Name = Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue on podman just set rootfull to true and repeat the setup process

```
podman machine set --rootful=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In our scenario we solved just adding the option

```
privileged: true
```

to the db2 service in the docker-compose.yml file